# Check if object exists in another object

Tags: javascript, object

I have an object like this:

```
var obj = {

 heroes: {
        "1": {
          label: "Spiderman"
        },
        "2": {
          label: "Iron Man"
        },
       }
}
```

What I want to know it, whether there is an object e.g. 2 in *obj.heroes*.

I tried this, but it didn't work:

```
var name = "heroes"; //Will be a for-loop later
try {
        if(name["2"] in obj) 
            console.log("There is an 2nd superhero!");

    } catch(e) {console.log(e);}
```

..got only errors: "Cannot read property '2' of undefined"

I hope you are able to help me. Thanks

Comment: You're trying to access a property named `2` in your `name` object (which is a string).  Remove the property accessor from if(name["2"])

Comment: Duplicate of most of these: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+check+nested+property+exists

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like:

```
try {
  console.log(obj.heroes["2"]);
} catch (e) {
  console.log('nope :c');
}
```

However, it would be better to store `heroes` as an array:

```
var obj = {
  heroes: [
    {
      label: 'Spiderman'
    },
    {
      label: 'Ironman'
    }
  ]
};
```

Using the array makes a little more sense since `heroes` consists of multiple `hero` objects.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
   if ("2" in obj[name]){
      console.log("There is an 2nd superhero!");
   }
```

---

But if you are trying to identify counts, it might be better if you used arrays

```
var obj = {
   heroes: [
            {label: "Spiderman"},
            {label: "Iron Man"}
           ]
}
```

And check with

```
if (obj[name].length > 1) {
    console.log("There is an 2nd superhero!");
}
```

Comment: Where exactly is the difference? Perfomance? Good style? Just for upgrading my basic knowledge.

Comment: if the `"2"` has intrinsic value then you should keep your original code, if - on the other hand - the 2 is just to signify that it is the second item, then you should use an array. It is the right tool for the job, plus it has properties and methods better suited to iterating/counting/adding/removing.. etc..

Answer (score 0):

If 2nd superhero doesn't exist the condition return false.

```
if(obj.heroes["2"]) 
    console.log("There is an 2nd superhero!");
```

Or :

```
var count = 0;
for (var x in obj.heroes) {
    if (obj.heroes.hasOwnProperty(x)) {
       count++;
    }
}
console.log("You see "+ count +" heroes.");
```

Answer (score 0):

this code will hunt it down for you

```
var delve = function(object, property, dodge) {
        if (!dodge) dodge = object;
        for (var i in object) {
            if (object[i] === dodge) continue;
            if (typeof(object[i]) == typeof({})) this.delve(object[i], property, dodge)
            if (i == property) console.log(object[i]);
        }
    }
delve(heroes,'2')
```